# String Tokenization and strstr in C - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, token

i am trying to read a file that has all the degree requirements on it. The format goes

```
# means comments, and i am trying to avoid those
a main class,followed by the level(professional,preprofessional),and then all the pre-requisites,a bar separating multiple pre-requisites
```

so here is what the file im trying to read looks like

```
# courses required for BS Computer Science, 2012-2013 catalog
# course,category,prerequisites,notes
# preprofessional
ENGL 1301,preprofessional,none,none
ENGL 1302,preprofessional,none,none
MATH 1426,preprofessional,MATH 1323,none
MATH 2425,preprofessional,MATH 1426,none
PHYS 1443,preprofessional,MATH 1426,none
PHYS 1444,preprofessional,PHYS 1443|MATH 2425,none
```

and when i tokenize and print the tokens im expecting for it to print something like

```
Class is ENGL 1301 and level is preprofessional
prereqs are none, none,

Class is ENGL 1302 and level is preprofessional
prereqs are none,none,

Class is MATH 1426 and level is preprofessional
prereqs are MATH 1323, none,
```

but the following code is segmentation faulting and not working correctly. I think my main trouble is trying to filter out the `#` in the file. I used `strstr` to look for it in the buffer and if it wasnt found,continue to tokenize each line. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("bscs-2014.csv","r");
    char* Class;
    char* level;
    char* prereq;
    char* token;
    char* del = ",|";
    char* ret;
    char buffer[1000];

    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL )
    {
        ret = strstr(buffer,"#");
        if(ret != NULL)
        {
            Class = strtok(buffer,del);
            level = strtok(NULL,del);
            printf("\nClass is %s level is %s\n",Class,level);

            while(token!= NULL)
            {
                token = strtok(NULL,del);
                printf("prereqs are %s, ",token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're *only* looking at lines containing (but not necessarily starting with) a `#`. When there is no `#` character, `(ret == NULL)`.

Comment: Where exactly does it crash?

Comment: Commas instead of pipes; formats change…(see [Implementation of linked list inside hash table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25130754/implementation-of-linked-list-inside-hash-table) for the context of this comment).

Comment: thanks, was first time implementing strstr

Comment: and `token` not assigned before `while(token!= NULL)`

Comment: what does the debugger say?

Comment: you are looking for lines containing # as opposed to those starting with # - although thats not yr main problem Paul Roub found that

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("bscs-2014.csv","r");
    char *Class, *level, *prereq, *note;
    char *del = ",\n", *token;
    char ch;
    char buffer[1000];

    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL ){
        if(1==sscanf(buffer, " %c", &ch) && ch == '#')//if(*buffer == '#')
            continue;
        Class  = strtok(buffer, del);
        level  = strtok(NULL,   del);
        prereq = strtok(NULL,   del);
        note   = strtok(NULL,   del);

        printf("\nClass is %s level is %s.\n", Class, level);

        int i, count = 0;
        for(i=0;prereq[i];++i)
            count += (prereq[i] == '|');
        printf("prereqs %s ", count ? "are" : "is");
        char *pre[count+1];
        for(i=0, token=strtok(prereq, "|");token;token = strtok(NULL, "|"), ++i){
            printf("%s", pre[i]=token);
            if(i != count)
                printf(", ");
            else
                printf(".\n");
        }
        printf("note is %s.\n", note);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```